# Could not find the entry point for windows application

Tags: winforms

How to find an entry point in the windows application as there will be a Main in the asp.net application where the execution starts to begin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Program.cs You will find Main() with Application.Run(new Form1()); 
Note : I consider you are talking about winforms.

Comment: ,yes tried these things before posting however could not find a program.cs i am new to winforms is there any other way ?

Comment: In C# this is how it works, in VB.Net you will find the start form by right clicking on Solution > Properties.

Comment: I guess you are asking for asp.net then, webpages with .aspx doesn't have entry points. Infact there is a partial class combined from two physical files 1: Default.aspx   2: Default.aspx.cs   when Default.aspx is rendered on server it is converted to a .cs file which is then compiled with it's partial class in Default.cs